# How to check if PHP function parameter value set by calling function or default value

Tags: php, function, parameters

I want to check if PHP functions parameter value set by calling function or its a default value

```
function our_round($value,$decimal=6){
   if($decimal == 6 && $value < 0){
     $decimal = 9; // default
   }

   if($decimal == 6 && && value < 0 && provided by calling function){
     // need this logic to code here.
     // keep 6 if 6 provided by provider
     $decimal  = 6;
   }

   return round($value,$decimal);
}

// calling
our_round(1.1234567); // decimal default value
our_round(1.1234567,2); // decimal value provided 
our_round(1.1234567,6); // decimal value provided
```

When calling function pass 6 in decimal, i want to check if its default or provided? to do some logic.

Comment: Does it really matter?

Comment: yes, please check updated code example

Comment: That code makes no sense

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but I agree that the code doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: But you can of course add a third boolean parameter `$overrideDefault = false` or something and then set it to `true` if you want.. although I still don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: Consider using `function our_round($value, $decimal = DEFAULT_VALUE)` and then you can compare `$decimal` to the default value. This can come from a `define`d value or (probably better) a class `const`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check what values were provided using [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php). However, I have to agree with the comments that such an approach makes no sense.

```
function func($a = 2) {
    var_dump($a, func_get_args());
}
func();
```

`func_get_args()` only returns arguments which were passed in when calling the function, not set by default values.

In your case, it would make more sense to make the second parameter nullable and then have the complex logic inside of the function's body.

```
function our_round(float $value, ?int $decimal = null) {
    if (null === $decimal && $value < 0) {
        $decimal = 9; // default
    } else {
        // need this logic to code here.
        // keep 6 if 6 provided by provider
        $decimal = 6;
    }

    return round($value, $decimal);
}
```

I would recommend taking a piece of paper and drow some kind of truth table of possible options. If you just want to assign a default value in a simple way you can use a ternary operator.

```
function our_round(float $value, ?int $decimal = null) {
    // assign default value
    $decimal ??= $value < 0 ? 9 : 6;

    return round($value, $decimal);
}
```